# Chain ID for connecting AWS private Ethereum Blockchain with Metamask

Tags: amazon-web-services, metamask, amazon-managed-blockchain

Can you please help me with this, I have created a private Ethereum blockchain in AWS using this template: https://aws.amazon.com/blockchain/templates/getting-started/

I wanted to connect this blockchain with metamask using EthJsonRPC url, what will be the chain id for connecting this metamask?

Answer (score 0):

If you click again on the CloudFormation template link, you will see that the default Chain ID value is 1234.

But in the case you changed that value and can't recall, you can easily double check the Chain Id, by requesting it via JSON-RPC.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ 
-d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"eth_chainId","params":[]}' \
<YOUR-INSTANCE-URL>
```

Also, make sure that the instance is reachable.